# chars like "è" and "à" are not correctly displayed from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, myisam

I have a problem with the characters displayed in a webpage when picked up from  a database.

Storage Engine: MyISAM

Collation: latin1_swedish_ci

In the databes the strings are stored correctly like in the following screen: [Data stored correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIp87.png)

But when they are displayed on the web page i get that "?" strange characters instead of the "è" that should be displayed. Like in this example:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WUD5.png)

I tried many different collations but i can't find a way to solve this problem. I hope it's something easy to solve. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have this in your HTML head? `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I didn't. I added <meta charset="UTF-8"> in my code but it did not solve my problem

Comment: try this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
`

Comment: We can't really tell if it is stored correctly without seeing `HEX(col)`.

Comment: Question Marks (regular ones, not black diamonds) (Se?or for Señor):

The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.  -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored